# What can cause HTML block elements to overlap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, hottowel

I started an MVC4 SPA web application based on the Hot Towel template. I started cleaning out header and footer stuff that I didn't want. One of the things I removed was from the file app.css that sets a `margin-top` for `section.main` to `80px`. I really don't want the header taking so much space. But I'm confused at the result. Even before I removed that I was seeing some odd behavior in the header based on the width of my Chrome browser window. Now that I have removed that, I see similar odd "wrapping" behavior that allows my header to overlap my content.

This is what my screen looks like when the width of the header is 979 pixels:
[image: Screenshot with header 979 pixels wide]

As I merely re-size the browser window, at 980 pixels I cross a threshold that causes the content to slide up under the header like this:
[image: Screenshot with header 980 pixels wide]

What could cause this overlap? Where can I look to try to make the `content` `section` remain strictly below the `header`? I do not see any `float` styles applied to the elements involved.

The really odd thing is that, although the `header` size goes to 0, the `nav` element it contains is clearly still visible with a proper size. How can a container be smaller than its content?

I found this in app.css that may be related:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
    .page-splash-message {
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-bottom {
        position: fixed;
    }

    footer span {
        padding: 10px 50px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at your CSS, search for media queries, investigate there. keyword ***threshold*** in "cross a threshold" ...

Comment: @Xander Thanks for the tip. I'm adding some CSS (momentarily) that I found that appears to be responsible. Maybe you can help describe/explain what it's doing that could cause the behavior described. Once I understand it, hopefully the solution will be clear.

Comment: If I had to guess (since you didn't provide the navbar-fixed-top code to look at), navbar-fixed-top (assuming the damnable Bootstrop is in use) sets the `<nav/>` element to display:fixed. This is why the margin-top was there in the first place, to fake the position of the main content down under the navbar that is floating overtop. Most likely the fixed-position is removed under 980px, or you only removed the margin-top from the >979px media query styles, which is why below 980px, it looks fine, but above, the content slides to where it should be.

Comment: It's because of `position: fixed`.

Comment: I tried changing it to relative and removing that block entirely, but it had no effect. Then I realized that there are a whole bunch more `@media` styles (which I've never heard of before today) referring to `979px` in `bootstrap-responsive.css`. This doesn't seem like a clean way to design a flexible layout. What would you recommend? Can I override the bootstrap styles in my `app.css` with something more sensible?

Comment: I prefer to chop out Bootstrap entirely, but that does mean going back to square one. If you're stuck with Bootstrap, one approach we took was to mirror the way Bs works... we created a separate dir for our LESS files, made a copy of bootstrap.less (renamed "project.less" for example), and commented out everything in that file. When we found something we needed to override, we copied that file from Bs's dir to our dir, and uncommented the include in our project.less file. Make sure there's a reference to your own bundle after bootstrap, and you get your styles overriding bootstrap's styles.

Comment: This could be helpful moving forward http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by changing my nav.html file from:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
(etc...)
</nav>
```

to:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
(etc...)
</nav>
```